# Asynchronous Recursive Calls using Box sdk - How to iterate all files in using iOS BOX sdk api

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, box-api

I am trying to iterate all images stored in a Box account.

The following code isn't correct and can't seem to find the error.

The problem seems to be waiting for all of the asynchronous recursive calls to complete in order to know when there are no more images to be fetched in order to signal completion

```
-(void)enumerateFiles
{
    [self recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:@"0" completion:nil];
}


-(void)recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:(NSString *)folderID completion:(void(^)())block
{
    static NSArray *imageExtensions;
    imageExtensions = @[@"jpg",@"jpeg",@"png"];
    [self enumerateFilesAtPath:folderID completion:^(BoxCollection *collection) {
        NSUInteger numberOfItems = collection.numberOfEntries;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            id model = [collection modelAtIndex:i];

            if ([model isKindOfClass:[BoxFolder class]])
            {
                BoxFolder *folder = (BoxFolder *)model;
                dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
                dispatch_group_enter(group);
                [self recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:folder.modelID completion:^{
                    dispatch_group_leave(group);
                }];
                dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
            } else if ([model isKindOfClass:[BoxItem class]])
            {
                BoxItem *item = (BoxItem *)model;
                NSString *extension = [[item.name pathExtension] lowercaseString];
                if ([imageExtensions containsObject:extension])
                {
                    [self.items addObject:model];
                }

            }
        }
        if (block)
        {
            block();
        }
    }];
}
-(void)enumerateFilesAtPath:(NSString *)folderID completion:(void(^)(BoxCollection *collection))block
{
    BoxCollectionBlock success = ^(BoxCollection *collection)
    {
        block(collection);
    };

    BoxAPIJSONFailureBlock failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSDictionary *JSONDictionary)
    {
        block(nil);
    };

    [[BoxSDK sharedSDK].foldersManager folderItemsWithID:folderID requestBuilder:nil success:success failure:failure];
}
```

Comment: Please notice, that you will start a large number of requests in parallel. Depending on the underlying implementation of the Box API, that might or might not become an issue. If the Box API doesn't restrict the number of simultaneous network requests (say < 8), then you will get quickly memory pressure issues and network requests may stall and finally time out.

Comment: Would like to comment on my own comment: as implemented in you code, using `dispatch_group_wait`, my statement above isn't true. However, the code above won't work that way anyway. I've put an answer, and it was kinda challenging and fun. Hope it works ;)

Comment: I'm the Box iOS SDK author. I'd like to mention that blocking in an API callback is not a good idea. The Box iOS SDK executes all completion/failure callbacks and NSURLConnection callbacks on a single thread. Blocking this thread prevents any other API call from making progress.

Comment: so how can i enumerate all files (of a certain type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to a viable approach is to make the inner loop, that is

`for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {..}`

a construct which *sequentially* invokes a number of *asynchronous* tasks and is *itself* asynchronous. The asynchronous task should be a block (`^`) which will invoke the outer method and will capture state so that its outer method `recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:` can be invoked in a *recursive manner*.

Note that this is *not* a recursion we know from functions, where a function calls itself *before* it returns, and where the state is hold on the program stack. Here, we rather have an *iteration* (asynchronous loop) - and there's no state on the stack, instead the state required for the "recursion" is hold in the variables captured in the blocks, and these reside on the heap.

That is, you need to transform the "for loop" (`for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {..}`) into some asynchronous method, e.g:

```
- (void) forEach:(NSArray*)objects applyTask:(task_t) completion:(completion_t)completionHandler;
```

where *task* is asynchronous, has a completion handler, and (conditionally) calls the outer method `recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:`.

This `forEach` construct could be implemented using a `NSOperationQueue`, whose max concurrent operations is set to one, and where the task is a `NSOperation` with a completion handler. Alternatively - and simpler in this case, it can be implemented using dispatch queues and a dispatch group. Or - even more simpler, it can be implemented using an "asynchronous loop". I'll show a possible implementation, see "NSArray Category `forEachApplyTask:completion:` below.

Now, suppose there is a Category for `NSArray` with an asynchronous `forEachApplyTask:completion:` method:

```
@interface NSArray (AsyncExtension)
- (void) forEachApplyTask:(unary_async_t)task completion:(completion_t) completion;
@end
```

This method takes a block of type `unary_async_t` as first parameter:

```
typedef void (^unary_async_t)(id input, completion_t completion);
```

and a completion handler as second parameter:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);
```

This typedef of a completion handler, is *generic* and can be used for all completion handler variants.

Let's suppose, the block *task* will be sequentially applied for each element in the receiver (the array). And suppose, this array is an array of "model"s in your original code -- you just need to create an array of "model"s out from the `BoxCollection` object.

When finished, the completion handler passes a result, which is an *array* containing the result of *each* task in the same order.

This task executes the block (`{..}`) in your former `for loop`.

Your method `recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:` will become inevitable asynchronous (since to invokes an asynchronous method in its implementation), and thus gets a completion handler parameter as well.

With the given assumptions made above, you can implement your problem as shown below:

```
-(void)recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:(NSString *)folderID 
                          completion:(completion_t)finalCompletionHandler 
{
    [self enumerateFilesAtPath:folderID completion:^(BoxCollection *collection) {
        NSArray* models = ...; // create an NSArray from the collection
        [models forEachApplyTask:^(id model, completion_t taskCompletionHandler) {
            if ([model isKindOfClass:[BoxFolder class]]) {
                BoxFolder *folder = (BoxFolder *)model;
                [self recursiveEnumerateFilesAtPath:folder.modelID completion:^(id result){
                    // result should be @"finished folder"
                    taskCompletionHandler(@"folder"); // taskCompletionHandler will never be nil
                }];
            } 
            else if ([model isKindOfClass:[BoxItem class]]) {
                BoxItem *item = (BoxItem *)model;
                NSString *extension = [[item.name pathExtension] lowercaseString];
                if ([imageExtensions containsObject:extension]) {
                    [self.items addObject:model];
                }
                taskCompletionHandler(@"item");
            }
        } 
        completion:^(id array){
            // this folder is finished. array may be for example @[@"folder", @"item", @"item"]          
            if (finalCompletionHandler) {
                finalCompletionHandler(@"finished folder");
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

**Caution:** not tested, you may experience issues!

Note, that everything runs asynchronous, and that there is no recursion whose state is put on the stack. The required state for recursively iterating the folders is put on the heap, enclosed in captured variables in the block.

---

The NSArray Category method `forEachApplyTask:completion:` is a reusable component, which can be utilized in many cases. One can implement it as follows:

#### Implementation of Category NSArray

```
/**
 Objective:

 Asynchronously transform or process an array of items - one after the
 other and return the result of each transform in an array.

 Synopsis:

 void transform_each(NSArray* inArray, unary_async_t task, completion_t completion);

 */


#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

/**
 Typedef of a generic completion handler for an asynchronous task.

 The parameter _result_ is the eventual result of the asynchronous
 task. In case the task has been failed _result_ SHALL be an
 NSError object.
 */
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result);


/**
 Typedef for an asynchronous "transform" function. It's an
 unary block taking an input as parameter and signals
 the eventual result via a completion handler.
 */
typedef void (^unary_async_t)(id input, completion_t completion);


/**
 `transform_each` sequentially applies an asynchronous transform function
 to each object in the input array _inArray_ and signals the result as an
 array containing the result of each transform applied to the input object.

 Function `transform_each` is itself a asynchronous function, that is,
 its eventual result will be signaled to the client through a completion
 handler.

 The result array contains the transformed objects in order of the
 corresponding input array.
 */
void transform_each(NSArray* inArray, unary_async_t task, completion_t completion);


// implementation


static void do_each(NSEnumerator* iter, unary_async_t task, NSMutableArray* outArray, completion_t completion)
{
    id obj = [iter nextObject];
    if (obj == nil) {
        if (completion)
            completion([outArray copy]);
        return;
    }
    task(obj, ^(id result){
        [outArray addObject:result];
        do_each(iter, task, outArray, completion);
    });
}

void transform_each(NSArray* inArray, unary_async_t task, completion_t completion) {
    NSMutableArray* outArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[inArray count]];
    NSEnumerator* iter = [inArray objectEnumerator];
    do_each(iter, task, outArray, completion);
}


/*******************************************************************************
    Example
 *******************************************************************************/

// A Category for NSArray

@interface NSArray (AsyncExtension)
- (void) async_forEachApplyTask:(unary_async_t) task completion:(completion_t) completion;
@end

@implementation NSArray (AsyncExtension)
- (void) async_forEachApplyTask:(unary_async_t) task completion:(completion_t) completion {
    transform_each(self, task, completion);
}
@end
```

See also: https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/6155227

Comment: Thanks for solution CouchDeveloper. How can I know all the items have been enumerated?

Comment: @niks If you use `async_forEachApplyTask:`: when all items in the receiver (the array) have been processed through applying the transform function (or block), the completion handler will be called. The completion handler will get a parameter which is an array containing the result of the transform function for each element in the receiver. For example, let the receiver be an array of URLs. Let the transform function be an async load, and its result be a NSData from the URL request - or an NSError if something went wrong. In the completion handler you can iterate through the result list.